# Projection of ListPointPlot3D on 2 axes

Tags: plotting, projection

I am just starting to learn Mathematica and I was trying to get projection of the list of points in ListPointPlot3D. I read about ViewPoint option. It shows the axes I need but doesn't show the points projected. What might the problem be?

Thank you.

```
list1 := {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 
 2, 1}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 
 4, 4}}

Show[ListPointPlot3D[list1, Filling -> Axis, 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, AxesLabel -> {D, Q, X}, 
PlotTheme -> "Marketing"], ViewPoint -> {0, \[Infinity], 0}]
```

**UPDATE:**
Added list var.

The 3d plot looks like this

[image]

And I want to get projection that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Looks ok.  But without knowing what `list1` is, it's hard to say what the problem might be.  Can you include it or code to generate it?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Added list values. They are static. And added some images to ilustrate what I want to achieve.

Comment: Your code produces this [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cTYbz.png) for me.  If I use `ViewPoint -> {0, -\[Infinity], 0}`, I get this [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1R7Vt.png) instead -- is that what you want?

Comment: Wow, wasn't aware of `PlotTheme->Marketing`. Would not have imagined that someone needs something like that. Anyway, why don't you just use a 3 by 2 Matrix to project your data and use the 2D plot (with `PlotTheme->Marketing` of course). Then you don't need to worry about lighting.

Comment: @MichaelE2 its just what I want. But for some reason I get [this graphics](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/f1b3c5d6-2f74-4be0-a00c-d292c1c2732e)

Comment: Are you using `PlotTheme -> "Marketing"`?  The view point in the question puts the back wall in front of the points.  If you have a white opaque wall instead of a semitransparent dark gray one, you would get the plot in your link.  (That's why I also showed the alternative with `-\[Infinity]` instead of `\[Infinity]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the right view point, one needs `-∞` in place of `∞`.  And just to be safe, I would set `ViewVertical` explicitly and use [`Deploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deploy.html) to prevent manual/mouse rotation of the graphics.

```
list1 = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1},
         {2, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 4}};

Deploy@ListPointPlot3D[list1, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, AxesLabel -> {D, Q, X}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", ViewPoint -> {0, -∞, 0}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also get a similar image with 2D graphics, dropping the second coordinate with `list1[[All, {1, 3}]]`:

```
ListPlot[list1[[All, {1, 3}]], Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", FrameLabel -> {D, X}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
t = Table[{i, Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 20, .1}];
f[l_, v_] := (v #) & /@ l
ListPointPlot3D[{t, f[t, {1, 1, 0} ], f[t, {1, 0, 1} ], f[t, {0, 1, 1} ]}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
GraphicsRow[ListPointPlot3D[{t, f[t, # ]}] & /@ Permutations[{1, 1, 0}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. Sorry for lack of the information in my question. I added an image of the projection I want to get.